# How can I change the default Grails/GORM lookup?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm new to Grails. I'm developing a web app that handles the records of a gymnasium, to make routines, exercises, etc.

I have this domain class Ejercicios:

```
class Ejercicios {
    String nombreEjercicio
    String idHoja
    String descripcion
    List<String> descripcionO

    static hasMany = [descripcionO: Descripciones]

    static transients = ['descripcionTrans']
    String descripcionTrans

    static mapping = {
        id column: "idHoja"
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        nombreEjercicio maxSize: 45
        idHoja blank: false
    }
```

The database table has the default Grails id named "idHoja", and another attribute named "id_hoja"

The thing here is that when I make a JSON parse from the rest API, I need GORM to look for exercises via the "id_hoja" attribute, not the "idHoja" because it'll cause a mismatch.

Comment: Can you show me how you `make a JSON parse from the rest API` ?

Comment: Of course! Here it is: {"objetivo":"Loose weight","fechaRealizacion":"2015-01-19T00:00:00Z","carne":114730445,"dias":[{"numDia":"1","ejercicios":[{"id":1,"descripcionTrans":"Descripcion del ejercicio"}]},{"numDia":"2","ejercicios":[{"id":3,"descripcionTrans":"test"}]}]}

(id is the "id_hoja" i'm talking about)

Comment: This JSON is made from Xcode, using a dictionary library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself!
The only thing I needed to was to make the JSON call with the name "idHoja" and that was it.